# How to select a value of "measure-object" directly? (powershell)

Tags: powershell, measure, pipelining

I am wondering about something. Not very important, but I am curious now...

Let's say we have a array:

```
PS C:\> $array
3
1129
1063
1139
1299
4446
1135
1096
1216
1075
```

And now we want to have the average of the values above. So I use `Measure-Object`:

```
PS C:\> $array | Measure-Object -Average | select Average

Average
-------
1360,1
```

okay. That's nice. But what if I only want to select the value, without getting some kind of "table" with the column name "average". I only want to have the value "1360,1" like a String or something.

I only know this way:

```
PS C:\> $tmp = $array | Measure-Object -Average | select Average

PS C:\> $tmp.Average
1360,1
```

So this works, but in this way I need a temporary variable which is not really needed... I think there must be an other easy way to get this in one line.

But I don't get it... sry! Can you help?

Comment: `$tmp = $($array | Measure-Object -Average).Average`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
$tmp = $array | Measure-Object -Average | select -expand Average
```

or this:

```
$tmp = ($array | Measure-Object -Average).average
```

Comment: FYI the full parameter is `-ExpandProperty`

Comment: @Matt  Usually I use  `-expa`, because is fastest ;)