# Measure-object to return an INT

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this is a simple question but I can't figure it out so here goes....

Running the below:

```
$cpu = Get-wmiobject win32_processor | measure-object -property LoadPercentage -average | select average
```

It returns something along the lines of Average: 10.

All I need from this is the numerial and I need it as an INT.

Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return only the integer sum of Measure-Object in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408111/how-do-i-return-only-the-integer-sum-of-measure-object-in-powershell) or [How to select a value of “measure-object” directly? (powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26097224/150605).

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an object with a single property. You need to remove the object portion of what's returned. Either use the -ExpandProperty parameter (between select and average), or use dotted notation: (Get-WmiObject ... LoadPercent -average).average

For what it's worth, you won't get an int, you'll get a double. Should be fine, however.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your variable at `int`, and use `-ExpandProperty` to expand out the property to get just the value

```
[int]$cpu = Get-wmiobject win32_processor |
             Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -average |
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty average
```

Comment: @Xyz Glad to hear. Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).